# pytest: import file mismatch with added __init__.py files to test directories

Tags: python, pytest

Have project directory like:

```
/beta
    /task one
        __init__.py
        test_solution.py
    /task two
        __init__.py
        test_solution.py
```

when try to collect tests via `python3 -m pytest --collect-only` i'm getting error:

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test_solution' has this __file__ attribute:
/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/bin/https:/github.com/vmred/untitled/beta/task one/test_solution.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/bin/https:/github.com/vmred/untitled/beta/task 
two/test_solution.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

`__pycache__` cleared several times, but not hepled.

What could be the issue in ?
Also tried to add `python_classes=test_solution.py` to `pytest.ini`, but also not helped.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have directory names with spaces. If replacing the space with an underscore doesn't work, you might want to consider renaming one of `test_solution.py` to another name. I think rn your `task <num>` folders don't work as modules so the test files are "replacing" each other. That confuses `pytest`.

Comment: "...or use a unique basename for your test file modules" may be the easiest way to fix it. That is, I'd rename them to `test_one.py` and `test_two.py` instead of having pytest decide between two `test_solution.py` files.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated: from the error report I'd conclude that pytest successfully imported both files. Spaces in path should be safe if you use Python's path-parsing functions; I bet pytest does that. Splitting by space is the problem of shell.

Comment: @9000 `pytest` did import both files, but because `task one` doesn't work as a module, so both test files are `test_solution` modules, which is probably why `pytest` is complaining. My hunch is that if the directories are `task_one` and `task_two`, the test files become `task_<num>.test_solution` which will make them distinct. That said, I'm not sure so I proposed both methods.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated: I agree; pytest explicitly suggests that in the error message.

Comment: yeah, if rename make unique file names it'll fix the issue but 
`In this case you can either create case/__init__.py and pytest/__init__.py files or rename the test files to unique names.` (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3151)

i guess creating  `__init__` files in each directory should fix the issue..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when my directory names contained hyphens. E.g.:

```
/beta
    /task-one
        __init__.py
        test_solution.py
    /task-two
        __init__.py
        test_solution.py
```

Converting the hyphens to underscores solved the problem.